# How to rephrase my D8 question to have it reopened?

Tags: discussion

**Question 1**

Yesterday I asked the question "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208299/how-to-upgrade-a-site-using-organic-groups-to-d8". Too bad, it got put on hold by a moderator (***not even 1 close review vote***). Today I noticed another question ("[How do I restrict access to forum?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208460/how-do-i-restrict-access-to-forum)") which got processed in the same way.

So does this mean that questions about D8, where you describe the functionality by referring to some D7 equivalent is not allowed on Drupal.SE? Can anybody help me to rephrase my question to have it reconsidered for reopen anyway?

**Question 2**

Apart from that, please teach me why these questions seem to be OK (they are **not** on hold or closed), so that I may learn from those to rephrase my question:

- [How can I add meta tags for pages created with views in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196032/how-can-i-add-meta-tags-for-pages-created-with-views-in-drupal-8)
- [How can enable multiple contact form in drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/134274/how-can-enable-multiple-contact-form-in-drupal-8)
- [Consuming RESTful web services](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128274/consuming-restful-web-services)
- [How to create a field that references a Views Block display in D8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198623/how-to-create-a-field-that-references-a-views-block-display-in-d8)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203807/what-are-the-alternatives-for-modules-user-points-combined-with-advanced-poll
- [Is there a Drupal 8 alternative for Inline Entity Form (to create an item while adding a reference)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149480/is-there-a-drupal-8-alternative-for-inline-entity-form-to-create-an-item-while)
- ... (on and on goes the list).

Comment: The answer is simply that they are open because nobody voted to close them. Any question asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource **is** off-topic. There is no exception, except in the case the question is asking about the difference between two modules; also in that case, that is to be seen case by case.

Comment: The previous comment is only a partial answer (to the last part of my question here, it doesn't help me to rephrase my question, as in my title) ... But note the ***not even 1 close review vote*** in my question here also, and still my question (and that other one from today) is put on hold. So is there any other reason (apart from "*nobody voted to close them*") why all those other questions are still open?

Comment: I am not sure what is the point about _1 close review vote_, but questions are closed also without _close review votes_. Users can vote to close directly from the question page; in fact, you don't find a question in the review queue for closing questions, if a user didn't vote to close it outside the review queue.

Comment: If there is not even 1 close review vote, then who or what else causes a question to be put on hold: "a" moderator puts it on hold. To my knowledge there is no other way to put a question on hold. So with that, why didn't "a" mod ever step in to close any of those "other" questions I mentioned? Also, if user X would have used the "close" link below the question, then that user X is shown ALSO as the very first username on the line with "Put on hold". Since my question (and the one from today) only has 1 (moderator) name, then there was nobody who hit that close link either.

Comment: Simply for the fact a single user doesn't have the time to close all the questions that should be closed, but moderators **do** close questions that are blatantly off-topic or low quality. The question is, eventually, why don't other users close questions that are blatantly off-topic or low quality, instead of answering them?

Comment: That would be another interesting "new" meta.drupal.SE question ... PS: Feel free to use the info in my "question 2"- part here to process them the very same way "whenever you have time for it". As long as that doesn't happen, there might be users who use them as a sample of what seems to be questions that are fine to ask (I actually used 1 of them as a template when I posted my question ...)

Comment: Older questions are never a justification for asking off-topic, or low-quality questions. If users think that, then they should not be surprised of getting their questions closed.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that the question is masquerading as a module recommendation, which is off-topic and one of our custom close reasons:

> Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme,
>   distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for
>   Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

There may be a meta discussion from when we discussed why we wanted this.

What can you do to make this acceptable for the site?  IMHO, nothing.  It doesn't show research (the Group module comes up as the number four result for me on Google in incognito mode when I search for "drupal 8 organic groups").  The Group module has been widely discussed at various camps / cons (think I sat in on one).  And, a generic version of the question would just be too broad.

Why did a moderator close this without any other close votes?  There are several reasons this could have happened.  It may have been flagged for moderator attention, and he decided to close it as off-topic.  He may have just been reading new questions and while his daily moderation duties and closed it as off-topic.

Why are those other questions open?  Probably because nobody flagged them, the community didn't cast close votes, a moderator didn't see them, or a moderator saw them and decided that they weren't close worthy.

Diamond moderators do not read each and every question and answer on the site and deem them worth or not.  Nor are we expected to.  The entire community moderates this site, to varying degrees based on their privileges.  The fact is, that the community on Drupal Answer doesn't vote to close that often, so the diamond moderators tend to do most of it on their own.  However, don't go ahead and flag these for the diamond mods to take care of.  You have the close vote privilege; use it and/or downvote as you deem appropriate.

We are in a somewhat weird time when we are going to get a decent amount of questions like this, until the contrib space and user comfort level increases with Drupal 8.  The same thing happened here when Drupal 8 hit feature freeze, and it happened when Drupal 7 came out.